# MySQL insert single variable with python

Tags: python, sql, pyodbc

Im having problem with single value inserts. 
Using pyodbc

```
LL= []
....
sqla = 'INSERT INTO d.table VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?)'
csr.executemany(sqla, LL)
```

Works, if LL is single column of data as a list...does not work.

```
LL= []
....
sqla = 'INSERT INTO d.table VALUES (?)'
csr.execute(sqla, LL)
```

How do I fix?

Then

```
LL= []
....
sqla = 'INSERT INTO d.table VALUES (?)'
csr.execute(sqla, LL)
```

If LL is Id only, The database table has cols of ID, AAA,BBB, CCC,
How do I insert....

```
LL= [['TDW'], ['TD0'], ['TD0'], ['TDW'], ['TD10'] ]
```

Comment: Could we see a snippet of what `LL` looks like with data in it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
sqla = 'INSERT INTO d.table (column_name) VALUES (?)'
```

This is right syntax of INSERT QUERY.